# Why does iskeyword contain colon for TeX files? And where is it set?

Tags: filetype-tex, keyword, default-settings

From [`iskeyword`'s doc](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27iskeyword%27) I read that its default on Linux is `@,48-57,_,192-255`.

However, when I open a `*.tex` file, `echo &iskeyword` gives `@,48-57,_,192-255,:`.

Where in the startup of Vim is that `:` appended to the default for TeX files?

And is there a rational as to why? I've just found annoying what happened when I pressed <kbd>*</kbd> while with the cursor on a word in prose immediately followed by `:`.

Comment: Check `:verbose set isk?`

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt, I'd say that's the answer.

Comment: I don't have the same behavior. Have your tried with a bare version of Vim?

Comment: @VivianDeSmedt, indeed, the command Crhistian Brabandt suggested showed that [vimtex](https://github.com/lervag/vimtex) is changing the option.

Comment: I believe this is for supporting LaTeX's expl3 syntax, but I feel it's more annoying than useful most of the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check what plugin or script is changing the value by using the following command:

```
:verbose set isk?
```